# A better way to set user permissions on elements using bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF desktop app.

I am also using sql lite to store tables/values.

One of these tables is User Permission Roles.

So.. when a User logs in the code will get a list of roles they have permission to use.

I then go through each record to set whether the button (ie) is enabled for then or not.

so in my ViewModel...

```
var myUserRoles = DB.CallMyMethodToReturnPermissions(User.Id);

foreach (role in myUserRoles)
{
    switch (role.Name)
    {
        case "CanDelete"
            if (role.Enabled)
            {
                UserPermissions.CanDelete = true;
            }
            break;
        case "CanAdd"
            if (role.Enabled)
            {
                UserPermissions.CanAdd = true;
            }
            break;

       ....etc etc etc
    }
}
```

and then in my View(s) something like this...

```
 <Button name="CanDelete "IsEnabled="{Binding UserPermissions.CanDelete}" />
 <Button name="CanAdd "IsEnabled="{Binding UserPermissions.CanAdd}" />

       ....etc etc etc
```

All this works well.  But looking to the future I can see added functionality and therefore User Roles/Permissions being set.

Therefore, should I consider another paradigm or hard code changes when I need to? Or is there a way to drive this from my DB table?

I only ask this question because I am relatively new to WPF and bindings so was wondering whether there are some clever alternatives?

Comment: I don't really do WPF but from a purely OOP standpoint, I would create a base class for buttons (or even controls) that has built-in logic to consume whatever security scheme you have and set its own enable status based on that.

Comment: @Juan Hi, thanks for responding. Yes that was one of the alternatives i would have considered but i wanted to see if i could make it work with  wpf bindings. Like a binding array for example.. Which if i did i would need to set bindings in t the code which i am not sure is the right way to go

Answer (score 3):

You could create you own implementation of ICommand.

**Draft example**:

```
public class PermissionRequiredCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public PermissionRequiredCommand(string role, 
                                     Action onExecute, 
                                     Action<bool> canExecute, 
                                     Func<string, bool> hasPermission)
    {
       // bla bla
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
         onExecute();
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
         return canExecute() & hasPermission(role);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
     public ICommand Delete {get;}

     public ViewModel(Authenticator authenticator)
     {
          Delete = new RequiresPermissionCommand(Roles.Delete, 
                                                 Delete,
                                                 CanDelete,
                                                 roleName => authenticator.HasPermission(roleName));

     }

}

public static class Roles
{
     public const string Delete = "CanDelete";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael this was similar to what i was considering. Thanks

Comment: I am just going to give a little but before accepting  just in case there is an alternative..

Comment: the way to go... :)

Comment: I am a bit slow but how do I pass the 'role' argument from view to Viewmodel?

Comment: so, the role parameter would be supplied by a parameter? so how/why is there a role parameter in the PermissionRequiredCommand method?

Comment: It was just a concept class, how you would like to transfer the role is up to you. So you can either control that from the View or from the ViewModel. Using the View you could use command parameters (in this case my example needs to be extended to support command parameters). Using the ViewModel you could use the contructor, to specify the role.

Comment: Ok, but your answer said 'you own implementation of ICommand.' which is what i am trying to do. I know about command parameters but this does not tally with your answer which intrigued me :)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have updated my answer the usage sample, where ViewModel is used.

Comment: No need to apologise. I apologise for being so thick

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever going to change the permission during run time?
I don't know what `UserPermissions` is. but if it is not a field but a static class then you might run into trouble for this. Since WPF cant really determine whether the property has changed or not if its a static property. But the fact that your binding isn't `x:static` so I assume it is a property. Which is fine.

other than that the binding will work well with your current structure given that all ViewModels has access to the `UserPermissions` instance.

I would also recommend looking into RelayCommand and move the `CanExecute` and click action in the view model. This way you will be able to put more logic to determine whether to enable the button without a converter.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer.  My Relaycommand and Can Execute are already in my ViewModel. Yes, I do know that WPF has issues with Static properties and yes you are correct in observing I am using properties.  I am not sure what your proposal is apart from doing what I am doing? Many thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson then you can move the IsEnabled binding into CanExecute parameter

Comment: steve, yes it is one of the options I was considering,  I wanted to see what my peers would suggest hence my question so thank you

Comment: Hi, I preferred the other answer even if that meant abandoning the isEnabled property. But thank you